# I have an issue when start my project that built in on drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal

I have an issue when start my project that built in on drupal:

Im got this Warning:
Warning: Table '.\xyz\sessions' is marked as crashed and should be repaired query: SELECT u.*, s.* FROM users u INNER JOIN sessions s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = 'u36ddivn597oqu2q6j6rel1ni7' in C:\xxx\includes\database.mysql.inc on line 136

how can I repair sessions table?

Comment: you can use PHPmyadmin to fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you All, I have fixed this issue using mysql command: "repair table sessions" :)